# Not working Prestashop - deleted .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop-1.5

I had a problem with showing images in Prestashop (they were displaying as question marks), so ***I tried delete a .htaccess file*** as I found on the internet. But the web is not working now, including Prestashop administration. Of course, I backed up the .htaccess file. So ***I tried to restore the backup but the web is still not working***.

Where could be the problem?

Project URL: http://www.herbik.cz/e-shop/

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You don't have to delete it manually. You may regenerate .htaccess by disabling and enabling Friendly URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is connected with your domain. You should check SEO & URLs settings and regenerate your .htaccess file.

Check the difference in the attached images:

http://www.herbik.cz/e-shop/herbik/themes/Herbik/img/hlogo.png

versus

http://www.herbik.cz/e-shop/themes/Herbik/img/hlogo.png

[image]

[image]